# (vim) How to remove word that has a specified character?

Tags: linux, vim, sed, find-and-replace

so I tried to remove any word that has a letter "a" in it with vim

I want to change this string

`hotel echo lima lima oscar whiskey oscar romeo lima delta`

to

`hotel echo whiskey romeo`

I hope I can do this on the vim, but no problem if I have to do this on paste, sed, etc. As long as I can do this on linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
s/\<\w*a\w*\> *//g
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/      # substitute, delimiter
    \<      # word boundary
    \w*     # 0 or more word character
        a       # letter a
    \w*     # 0 or more word character
    \>      # word boundary
     *      # 0 or more spaces
/       # delimiter
/g      # delimiter, global
```

Comment: thank you, it worked!

Comment: @ecanusyofiel: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the cursor at the start of the line, search for `/a`, then
`daw` ('delete a word'). You can then jump to the next match with `n` and press
the `.` to repeat the deletion (and just keep spamming `n` + `.`). If the line
is very long, you can record a macro with (put the cursor at the start of the
line) with `qqndaw`, and just repeat the macro 100 times (or some sufficiently
large number) with `100@q`.

Comment: @Toto's answer is much better than mine!